How to install amplify cli in android studio terminal
Not able to use npm or curl to install amplify cli in android studio terminal.
To Install a Amplify-cli this is the command:
npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
But npm is not installed.
I tried to install npm , but i can only use npm in powershell or cmd but not in android studio terminal.
I need to run amplify command for AWS in android studio terminal.
like
amplify init
amplify configure
